# Python BeautifulSoup find using re.compile for end of string

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Using the following example, how do I utilize BeautifulSoup to find (or select) the SECOND INPUT element.

```
<form>
<input id="a:b:c" ...>
<input id="a:b" ...>

</form>
```

I tried to use .find('input', id=re.compile('b')) which of course gives me the FIRST element.

I am looking for a way to get directly to the second, without using FindAll and iterate.

Is there a way to improve the Regular Expression?

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [BeautifulSoup documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments), if you know exactly the ID you're looking for, you can pass it in as a string rather than a regex:

```
soup.findall('input', id='a:b')
```

Otherwise, if you're always looking for exactly the second `input` that matches your regex, the documentation suggests that `soup.findall` gives you a list rather than a generator. This means you don't need to iterate, since you can just ask for the second result directly:

```
soup.findall('input', id=re.compile('b'))[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Add $ after b in your regex, that should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, that was excatly what was needed.